# Updating data sources in .aprx files

Tags: arcpy, layers, data-source

I am about to break a lot of data sources in our team's .aprx files because we are overhauling the places we are storing our data.  Our data is stored in shapefile and file geodatabase formats.

Is there a way to programmatically do this?  I have found snippets online that answer slightly different questions, like changing a gdb or SDE connection. But in my case it might be :

```
old1 = myFolder\myGDB.gdb\myFC
new1 = myFolder\myotherFolder\myGDB.gdb\myFC2
old2 = myFolder\myOld.shp
new2 = newFolder\myNew.shp
```

etc. For me changing the GDB isn't enough... sometimes the feature class name will be changed as well.

I have so far got a script that

- goes thru folders to look for .aprx files
- uses the aprx object to return broken links eg. my_broke_list = my_aprx.listBrokenDataSources()
- and I have stored my data changes in a spreadsheet. I use pandas to read the columns for old and new.

The missing piece is updating the connection.  I've tried it different ways but each time the result is a new aprx files with the same old broken links.
I've tried using the aprx property and the layer properties.

So far my only conclusion is that lyr.updateConnectionProperties(old,new)  doesn't do what it is supposed to be doing...

My small part that just does the layer connection fix is :

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

aprx = r"Q:\blah\testBrokenLinks\small_test.aprx"
aprxNew = r"Q:\blah\testBrokenLinks\small_test4.aprx"

arpxObj = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(aprx)
old = r'Q:\blah\testBrokenLinks\lfsa000b21a_e.shp'
new = r'Q:\blah\testBrokenLinks\postal_codes.shp'

for m in arpxObj.listMaps():
    for lyr in m.listLayers():
        if lyr.isBroken:
            print('broke')
            if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
                if lyr.dataSource == old:
                    print(old)
                    lyr.updateConnectionProperties(old,new)
                    print(new)

arpxObj.saveACopy(aprxNew)
print ('finito')
```

Comment: Please format your code, with python indentation is vitally important so without that it's not worth reading. There is an article https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/arcpy/mapping/updatingandfixingdatasources.htm that might give you a few pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the `updateConnectionProperties()` method in arcpy is either horribly broken, or that there is a significant mis-understanding between the documentation and myself (I'm prepared to admit that it could be the latter).  I did actually log a support request with ESRI back in 2021, but according to my email records, it was never resolved (closed because I found another work-around).

Eventually, I found a work-around that avoids using that method completely.  Instead, it uses the Python access to what ESRI calls the CIM (Cartographic Information Model).  [See here for ESRI's documentation on Python CIM access](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm).

Here's how I do it in one of my Python script tools:

```
for lyr in lyrFile.listLayers():
    arcpy.AddMessage(4*"." + lyr.longName)
    lyrCIM = lyr.getDefinition('V3')
    if not hasattr(lyrCIM, "featureTable"):
        arcpy.AddMessage(8*"." + "Ignoring connection data for non-feature-table layer:  {}".format(lyr.longName))
        continue
    dataConnection = lyrCIM.featureTable.dataConnection
    datasetName = dataConnection.dataset.split(".")[-1]
    dataConnection.workspaceFactory = "FileGDB"
    dataConnection.workspaceConnectionString = "DATABASE={}".format(sourceWorkspace)
    dataConnection.dataset = datasetName
    lyr.setDefinition(lyrCIM)
```

As you can see, this is designed to work against a layer file (.lyrx), but it should also work for a project file (.aprx).

Of course, you'll need to tweak this code to suit your situation.  In particular, you may need to set values other than 'FileGDB' for the `workspaceFactory` and your `workspaceConnectionString` may need to be formatted differently if not using a fGDB (and similarly the `dataset` value).  If your spreadsheet can include enough information, though, you should be able to make this work.

Comment: Nice! Shame esri did not resolve the issue with updateConnectionProperties() method in arcpy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that I've done it, in another tool that I'd forgotten about (copied in from ESRI forum where I'd posted it previously)...

The code snippet below is part of my Python tool which makes this easy.

In my code, this is run within a loop for multiple layers and it very slow, as it has to wait for ArcGIS Pro to add each layer to the map and then remove it again.  ArcGIS Pro is the most unresponsive application I've used on any OS anywhere anytime ever (can you tell it annoys me?  A lot.).

Before this snippet, the logic gets a list of all featutre classes in the new Data Source and for each of the old feature classes to be changed, it checks the list to make sure that there is one with a matching name in the new Data Source to use as 'fcNew'.  If there is not, then my particular tool will output a warning, and depending on another parameter in the tool, may also remove the layer if its data source could not be updated (due to no matching FC in the new data source).

```
        fcNew = os.path.join(newDS, fcName)
        tmpLayer = map.addDataFromPath(fcNew)
        newProperties = tmpLayer.connectionProperties
        map.removeLayer(tmpLayer)
##        arcpy.AddMessage("OLD connection properties:\n{}".format(layer.connectionProperties))
        layer.updateConnectionProperties(layer.connectionProperties, newProperties)
##        arcpy.AddMessage("NEW connection properties:\n{}".format(layer.connectionProperties))
```